# Rspec2 Missing template Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, rspec2

Upgraded form Rails 2 to 3. And RSpec 1 to 2. It looks like capybara/webrat is trying to find the template when I only want it to find the action. What is a possible workaround?

#### The error

```
Failure/Error: delete :read, :id => @feed_entry.id, :format => 'json'
Missing template feed_entries/read with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :rhtml, :rxml, :builder], :formats=>[:json], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/Users/maletor/Sites/3md/app/views", ...
# ./app/controllers/feed_entries_controller.rb:37:in `read'
# ./app/controllers/feed_entries_controller.rb:35:in `read'
# ./spec/controllers/feed_entries_controller_spec.rb:200
```

#### app/controllers/feed_entries_controller#read

```
def read
  if request.post?    
    @feed_entry.read_by(current_account)
  elsif request.delete? 
    @feed_entry.unread_by(current_account)
  end    

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html  { redirect_to topic_path(params[:topic_id]) }
    format.json  { render :nothing => :true, :status => :no_content }
    format.plist { render :nothing => :true, :status => :no_content }
  end
end
```

#### spec/controllers/feed_entries_controller_spec.rb:200

```
delete :read, :id => @feed_entry.id, :format => 'json'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you can't do `render :nothing => true` with a status different from 200. An alternative is not using `render`, but using `head :no_content`.